# Продолжить отрезок в пространстве и узнать координаты окончания продолжения?

Tags: c++, 3d

В пространстве есть 2 точки (A и B) с определёнными координатами (x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2). Между ними линия (отрезок AB). Эту линию надо продолжить со стороны первой точки (A) на определённую длину (L), и получить координаты (x3, y3, z3) точки (C) окончания продолженной линии (CA). Помогите составить формулу.

Comment: "Помогите составить формулу." - Поможем. Что Вы уже сделали кроме копирования задания в вопрос?

Answer (score 2):

1. Находим вектор `AB`: `AB = B - A = (x2 - x1, y2 - y1, z2 - z1)`.
2. Находим длину вектора `AB`: `|AB| = sqrt( (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 + (z2-z1)^2 )`.
3. Рассчитываем сонаправленный вектор `t` так, чтобы его длина равнялась `L`: `t = (L / |AB|) * AB`.
4. Разворачиваем вектор `t` в противоположную сторону: `t := -t`.
5. Вектор `t` есть вектор `CA`: `t = C - A`. Находим `C`: `C = t + A`.